# Qt +hiding window after startup

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to hide window after its startup.
I have own window-class which is inherited from QMainWindow.
I rewrote showEvent like this:

```
void showEvent (QShowEvent *evt)
{
   if (firstShow)
   {
     hide();
     firstShow = false;
   }
   else
   {
      QMainWindow::showEvent(evt);
   }
}
```

But it doesn't work. firstShow is a boolean variable, which is true at start.
Language: c++

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't quite follow. Surely you just don't call show() on your main window in the first place?